# Making a mathematical equation string valid by inserting * between multiplied members

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to change this expression `pow((x),(2))sin(x)` into this `pow((x),(2))*sin(x)` by inserting a `*` in the middle.

Attempted with this javascript code:

```
function cal(str)
{
  var regex = /([a-z]+)\(\(([a-z]+)\),\(([0-9]+)\)\)\(([a-z0-9\*\+]+)\)([\*\-%\/+]*)/;
  var replacement = "$1($2($4))*$3($5)";
  while(str.match(regex))
  {
    str = str.replace(regex,replacement);
  }

  return str;
}

var t = cal("power((x),(2))sin(x)");
alert(t);
```

Comment: What does it have to do with python?

Comment: @m01 what i meant was pow((x),(2))sin(x) expression is valid only if it is entered as pow((x),(2))*sin(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = /(\))\s*([\w\d])/g;
str = str.replace(regex, "$1*$2");
```